# How to transform a unix timestamp in nanoseconds to seconds without losing precision [C++ 17]

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I need the unix time in **nanoseconds** for calculation purposes **in seconds**, but **dont want to lose "precision"**. So I tried to transform the integer variable to double and expected a 128 divided by 10 to be a 12.8. But in this example I lost precision and only got 12. What am I doing wrong, or where is my understanding problem? **This is what I tried**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int64_t a = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        
    double b = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
    
    cout<<(a) << " ns \n";
    
    cout.precision(9);
    cout << fixed << b << " s" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1668199112421581468 ns 
1668199112.000000000 s

Wanted: 1668199112.421581468 s
```

Comment: If you want decimals, don't use integers. Yes, you declared as a double, but you do integer division. Which spits out... an integer. Which you then store in a double.

Comment: Ahhhhh... the chrono part returned a integer. This works for me!! Thanks for the hint!

    double b = static_cast<double>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()) / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);

Comment: @gear: That looks horrible. Avoid that `count`, and just let `duration_cast` do the math for you. You need the division in your code because `count()` throws away the period, and just gives you a raw number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` returns an integral type, because `std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep` (the representation type) is an integral type with at least 64 bits.

You can use `std::chrono::duration<double>`, which supports fractional seconds. No need to do the math yourself, `duration_cast` knows about `std::chrono::duration::period`.

Comment: Ok, just tried this: double b = std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(); and it works fine. But in your comment above you suggested to avoid count(). But without it, I dont get my unix time? Can you specify what you meant?

Comment: And how does the std::chrono::duration<double> know, that it should output seconds with decimal places instead of for example milliseconds with decimal places?

Comment: Note that currently `double` can hold a floating point count of seconds since 1970 with a precision of 238ns.  I.e.  whatever value you get, the next highest value the `double` can represent is 238ns more.

Comment: Ok this is acceptable. Actually microseconds also would fulfill the precision requirements for my following calculation. So reading the current unix timestamp by std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() would be a proper way in your eyes?

Comment: If it helps, a 1h video tutorial on chrono: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Wow @Howard Hinnant, I literaly read your name 5 times today while searching for timestamp topics on stackoverflow and everyone was suggesting your library. I will take a look on your video, thanks :)